# Formal deduction (simple question)

Tags: logic

If $T \vdash A \rightarrow B $ and $T \vdash A$, can we say that $T \vdash B$?

Comment: I think it follows by the deduction theorem, but I cannot find the precise way of doing it.

Comment: @user99680: The deduction theorem is the opposite direction, if $T\cup\{A\}\vdash B$ then $T\vdash A\to B$. This direction is modus ponens, and it's usually a simple application of derivation rules which are given with the proof system.

Comment: If $T$ proves that if $A$ then $B$, and $T$ proves $A$, then $T$ proves $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(T\vdash (A\to B)) \land (T\vdash A)$$

$$\implies T\vdash ((A\to B) \land A)$$

$$\implies T\vdash B$$

$$\therefore (T\vdash (A\to B)) \land (T\vdash A) \to (T\vdash B)$$

Comment: Approved by the King.

Answer (score 0):

> If $T \vdash A \rightarrow B $ and $T \vdash A$, can we say that $T \vdash B$?

No, this is not generally true.  It is a theorem which must be proven for each logic.  It has been proven for natural deduction, and hilbert style logics.  In fact, they are designed around making this statement true, so the proof is very trivial.

But it is a trivial effort to create a logic where the statement isn't true.  For example, we could simply create a logic with no axioms or inference.  Or we could swap $\land$ and $\to$ in natural deduction inferences.

If you had qualified your question with "If $T \vdash A \rightarrow B $ and $T \vdash A$, can we say that $T \vdash B$ *in natural deduction*" (or another common logic) then a proof of the claim could be made.